# Do all files get updated on application cache manifest update? or just the changed ones?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, manifest

If I am using a cache manifest file like so

```
CACHE MANIFEST:
#version 1.0
products.html
scripts.js
styles.css
```

And then I make changes to scripts.js but DO NOT change products.html OR styles.css.  I then update the commented version number, so now my manifest file looks like so

```
CACHE MANIFEST:
#version 1.1
products.html
scripts.js
styles.css
```

The question is:  will all three files get downloaded? or only the scripts.js file that changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to [this website](http://appcachefacts.info/):

> When updating an existing appcache, the browser sends standard
>   If-Modified-Since headers, so it skips re-downloading files that have
>   not changed.

However, I would really like a more authoritative source if possible before closing the question.